# Is the dihedral group $D_n$ nilpotent? solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

Is the dihedral group $D_n$ nilpotent? solvable?

I'm trying to solve this problem but I've been trying to apply a couple of theorems but have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Dear user, One of the most basic facts about the dihedral group of order $2n$ is that it contains a normal and cyclic subgroup of rotations of order $n$ with index $2$.  If you don't see straight away that this implies that the dihedral group is solvable, then it would probably be a good idea to review the relevant background to this question carefully, so that your intuition catches up with your formal understanding.  (What I mean is that, while nilpotency may a little more subtle, for solvability it shouldn't be a matter of applying theorems, but rather just combining the definition ...

Comment: ... with the basic structural properties of the dihedral group.) Regards,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Theorem:***$D_n$ is nilpotent iff $n=2^i$ for $i\geq0$.*

The following is the proof as given [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/dih2n-is-nilpotent-if-and-only-if-n-is-a-power-of-2/):

> ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $D_{2n}$ is nilpotent. Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $n$. Then $r^{n/p}$ is an element of order $p$ in $D_{2n}$; in particular, $r^{n/p} \neq r^{-n/p}$. Now $|s| = 2$ and $|r^{n/p}| = p$ are relatively prime, so that, $sr^{n/p} = r^{n/p}s$; a contradiction. Thus no odd primes divide $n$, and we have $n = 2^k$.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) We proceed by induction on $k$, where $n = 2^k$.
>
> For the base case, $k = 0$, note that $D_{2 \cdot 2^0} \cong Z_2$ is abelian, hence nilpotent.
>
> For the inductive step, suppose $D_{2 \cdot 2^k}$ is nilpotent. Consider $D_{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}}$; we have $Z(D_{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}}) = \langle r^{2^k} \rangle$, and so, $D_{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}}/Z(D_{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}}) \cong D_{2 \cdot 2^k}$ is nilpotent. Thus, $D_{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}}$ is nilpotent.

**Theorem:** *$D_{2n}$ is solvable for all $n\geq1$.*

To prove this, I will use the above fact (see [here](http://planetmath.org/dihedralgroupproperties)).

> When $n=1$, $D_{2n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ which is nilpotent and thus solvable. When $n>1$, $D_{2n}/\langle r\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\langle r\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$. Both $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are nilpotent and so they are both solvable. As extensions of solvable groups are solvable, $D_{2n}$ is solvable for all $n>0$.

Comment: Could the downvote be explained?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but using the argument "$G$ is nilpotent and so is solvable" when $G$ is abelian, or to say that "extensions of solvable groups are solvable" when you've explicit construct of series with abelian quotients, is somewhat weird...

Answer (score 7):

A general proof that $D_n$ is solvable for all $n \geq 1$.

Here is the normal series with abelian quotients:
$$\{e\} \trianglelefteq \langle \sigma \rangle \trianglelefteq D_n$$

$$\langle \sigma \rangle/\{e\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_n,   D_n/\langle \sigma \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$ both obviously abelian, therefore $D_n$ is solvable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach to show that $D_{n}$ is nilpotent iff $n$ is a power of $2$:

Suppose $n\geq 3$ and denote $\textbf{Z}=\textbf{Z}(D_n)$ as the center of $D_n$. [It is not difficult to see](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Dihedral_Group) that $\textbf{Z}=1$ if $n$ is odd and that $\textbf{Z}=\langle r^{n/2}\rangle$ if $n$ is even. Here $r$ denotes de rotation of $D_{n}$ and $s$ the reflection of $D_n$. Now, if $n$ is even, we have that $D_n/\textbf{Z}\cong D_{n/2}$. This follows because the cosets $r\textbf{Z}$ and $s\textbf{Z}$ satisfy the presentation equations for $D_{n/2}$, that is, $$(r\textbf{Z})^{n/2}=(s\textbf{Z})^2=(r\textbf{Z}s\textbf{Z})^2=\textbf{Z}.$$
Thus, the [upper central series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Upper_central_series) of $D_n$
$$1\leq \textbf{Z}\leq Z_2\leq Z_3\leq \cdots$$
will reach $D_n$ iff the numbers $n$, $n/2$, $n/4$, ..., are all even.