# when a dihedral groups is nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory

well i found this question answered in

[Is the dihedral group $D_n$ nilpotent? solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834966/is-the-dihedral-group-d-n-nilpotent-solvable)

but the answer involves the sylow thm which i haven't studied.
i'm studying bhattacharya and this question appears before the books starts to talk about the structure thms of groups...i wonder if it is possible to answer the question at this moment

thanks for your help

Comment: They are all solvable. Can you prove that?

Comment: yes that is in fact easy...what bothers me is the nilpotency

Comment: Here is one possible approach in summary. If $n$ is a power of $2$ then $D_n$ is a $2$-group and hence nilpotent. If $n$ is odd then $D_n$ has trivial centre and so it cannot be nilpotent. Otherwise $D_n = 2^km$ with $m$ odd, and $D_n$ has a quotient group isomorphic to $D_m$, so it is not nilpotent.

Comment: @DerekHolt what is a $2$-group?? I keep trying to look this up and figure out what it is, but I can't find anything even remotely relevant!

Comment: For positive integer $\alpha$ and prime $p$, a group of order $p^{\alpha}$ is a p-group. In regards to Sylows Theorem: for any group of order $p^{\alpha}m$ (where $(m,p)=1$, there always exisits at least one $p$-subgroup

Comment: @DerekHolt Clearly $D_n$ is nilpotent when $n=2^k$, could you give some hints that how we can know the class of nilpotency.