# Normal Groups of Dihedral Group of order n>2

Tags: abstract-algebra

In order to show that the dihedral group $D_n$ is not simple for $n>2$ I am attempting to find a subgroup of $D_n$ that has index $2$ knowing that any subgroup of index 2 is normal. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The dihedral group is the group of symmetries of an $n$-gon. Can you think of a natural $n$-element set (subgroup) of symmetries?

Comment: Since $D_n$ is solvable for all $n\ge 1$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834966/is-the-dihedral-group-d-n-nilpotent-solvable), it i s also clear that it is not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ of all rotations has always index two in $\;D_{2n}$

Comment: How would you describe this group algebraically?

Comment: If $\;D_{2n}:= \langle\,s,t\;:\;s^2=t^4=1\,,\,sts=t^{n-1}\;\rangle\; $ , then $\;R:=\langle\,t\,\rangle\;$